# Incorrect SQL syntax from string Contains and StartsWith

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate

```
session.Query<Product>().Where(p =>  p.Name.Conains("Paper"))
```

creates to the following SQL:

```
(...)
where prod1_.Name like ('%' || 'Paper' || '%')
```

What I would like to see is obviously: `like '%Paper%'`

I also have the same issue with `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`.
NHibernate version is 3.2.0 and the dialect is `NHibernate.Spatial.Dialect.MsSql2008GeometryDialect` if it matters.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the dialect `NHibernate.Spatial.Dialect.MsSql2008GeometryDialect`. When changing the dialect to `NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect` the created SQL is correct.